# CUDA bounds checker?

Tags: memory, cuda, valgrind

Is there a tool equivalent to a bounds checker or purify or valgrind for CUDA?

I'm basically looking for something that might tell me if I'm reading or writing outside of allocated memory.

Answer (score 4):

NVIDIA have released CUDA memcheck which does exactly this. It's available in the [3.0 beta](http://forums.nvidia.com/index.php?showtopic=149959) toolkit, you'll need to be a registered developer to download it. In addition, NVIDIA have also release [Nexus](http://www.nvidia.com/nexus) which is their debugger/profiler for Visual Studio 2008 (Vista/7/2008) and includes memory checking (see the [features list](http://developer.nvidia.com/object/nexus_features.html)).

Comment: I actually installed the 3.0 beta toolkit and didn't find it there. Didn't try nexus yet.

Answer (score 3):

If you compile in emulation mode, you can use Valgrind itself to detect memory access problems in your kernels.